# Is it a risk to put the CSRF Token in a GET request URL?

Tags: security, csrf, csrf-protection, owasp, csrf-token

TL;DR Why is it bad to put a CSRF Token in the GET request parameter?

Set up to the problem.

I have a search form on a SaaS app where the CSRF token is being injected for every form including the GET forms. This seems bad to me, but I can't articulate why and I'm being asked to.

All traffic is encrypted. So the GET parameters can't be wire sharked and scraped.

The worst scenario I can see here is some sort of social engineering where a malicious actor would ask someone to copy the URL and the user just handing it over without thinking it's dangerous.

Otherwise I can't really think of a scenario where a drive by hack is possible without the hacker going through the trouble of setting up a man in the middle scenario, and in which case they would probably be set up to do worse things without that CSRF Token.

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [OWASP CSRF Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) and specially the section about ***Disclosure of Token in URL***

Comment: There's no such section `Disclosure of Token in URL`

Comment: From the [Synchronizer Token Pattern](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#synchronizer-token-pattern) section of the above reference;

"Make sure that the token is not leaked in the server logs, or in the URL. CSRF tokens in GET requests are potentially leaked at several locations, such as the browser history, log files, network appliances that log the first line of an HTTP request, and Referer headers if the protected site links to an external site."